# CherryPy configuration tools.staticdir.root problem

Tags: python, configuration, relative-path, cherrypy

How can I make my static-file root directories relative to my application root folder (instead of a hard-coded path)?

In accordance with CP instructions (http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/StaticContent) I have tried the following in my configuration file:

```
tree.cpapp = cherrypy.Application(cpapp.Root())
tools.staticdir.root = cpapp.current_dir
```

but when I run `cherrpy.quickstart(rootclass, script_name='/', config=config_file)`
I get the following error

*builtins.ValueError: ("Config error in section: 'global', option: 'tree.cpapp', value: 'cherrypy.Application(cpapp.Root())'. Config values must be valid Python.", 'TypeError', ("unrepr could not resolve the name 'cpapp'",))*

I know I can do configuration from within the main.py file just before quickstart is called (eg. using os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**))), but I prefer using the idea of a separate configuration file if possible.

Any help would be appreciated (in case it is relevant, I am using CP 3.2 with Python 3.1)

TIA
Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer to a module inside configuration entries, CherryPy first looks for that module in `sys.modules`. So one solution would be to `import cpapp` just before you call quickstart.

But if that lookup in `sys.modules` fails, CherryPy tries to `__import__` the module. Since that is also failing, you might need to investigate whether your `cpapp.py` module is indeed importable at all.

See the `lib/reprconf.py` module for all the gory details.

Comment: Hi fumanchu - thanks for the reply.  As far as I can see there is no cpapp.py module to import, so I can't try that option.  I think on reflection that the best solution may be to have a separate configuration file for each application (which I guess was the intended designed use), hard-code tools.staticdir.root, then set all the other sub-folders (css, js, etc.) relative to the root.

Comment: cpapp.py is wherever you have your Root class declared. if your Root class is found in myapp/main.py, for example, then your config needs to say "tree.cpapp = cherrypy.Application(myapp.main.Root())"