# Is there a way to use relative paths while serving static files using CherryPy 3.2 with a config file?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I recently asked this related question:
[Problems serving static files favicon.ico and robots.txt in CherryPy 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308164/problems-serving-static-files-favicon-ico-and-robots-txt-in-cherrypy-3-1)

In my config file, I have an absolute path described.  Is there a way to make it a relative path?  The reason is that I'm on a team.  My teammates as well as my server use different paths for the location of our code.

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.root = "/projects/mysite/trunk/root"
tools.staticdir.dir = ""
tools.staticfile.root = "/projects/mysite/trunk/root"

[/favicon.ico]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "images/favicon.ico"

[/robots.txt]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "robots.txt"

[/images]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "images"

[/css]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "css"

[/js]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "js"
```

Comment: relative to where the starting python file lives.  The Python file that loads this configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I've only started playing with Cherrypy so there may be good reasons to not do this but below is what I added to the .conf file to serve files form the static directory.  Note that I'm in the directory above static when I execute the python program.

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.root = os.getcwd()

[/static]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "static"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
    'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.curdir), 'trunk/root'),
```

Comment: No -- because that's not using a config file.  That would be specifying the config in the code.

Comment: Seems there was a similar thread:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954370/cherrypy-configuration-tools-staticdir-root-problem